# Login Validation Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

require the user to enter a username that is 3 or more alphanumeric characters.
o require the user to enter a password that is 8 or more characters.

I am working on a login form, I have create html, css, and javascript files. I have created the validation functions but when I load my html I don't see the validation messages.

var subButton = document.getElementById('submit', validation);

```
    function validation(e) {
        let data = {};
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e);
        errors.forEach(function (item) {
            item.classList.add("hide");
        })
        let error = false;
        inputs.forEach(function (el) {
            let tempName = el.getAttribute("userName");
            if (tempName != null) {
                el.style.borderColor = "#ddd";
                if (el.value.length == 0 && required.includes(tempName)) {
                    addError(el, "Required Field", tempName);
                    error = true;
                }
                if (tempName == "email") {
                    let exp = /([A-Za-z0-9._-]+@[A-Za-z0-9._-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)\w+/;
                    let result = exp.test(el.value);
                    if (!result) {
                        addError(el, "Invalid Email", tempName);
                        error = true;
                    }
                }
                if (tempName == "password") {
                    let exp = /[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;
                    let result = exp.test(el.value);
                    if (!result) {
                        addError(el, "Only numbers and Letters", tempName);
                        error = true;
                    }
                    if (!(el.value.length > 8)) {
                        addError(el, "Needs to be greater than 8 characters", tempName);
                        error = true;
                    }
                }
                data[tempName] = el.value;
            }
        })
    }

    function addError(el, mes, fieldName) {
        let temp = el.nextElementSibling;
        temp.classList.remove("hide");
        temp.textContent = fieldName.toUpperCase() + " " + mes;
        el.login.borderColor = "red";
        el.focus();
    }
```

I don't see the validation alerts

Comment: What is `el`? Cannot see that is is given a value

Comment: can you include the relevant html

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head></head><body>
<title>Login Form</title>
 
   
   
 <form name="myform"> 
    <h2>Login Form</h2> 
    <link href="login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src= C:\Users\Fuzion\Desktop\Assignment4\login.js></script>
    User Name: <input type="text" name="userName"><br>
    <span class="error hide"></span><br>
    Password: <input type="Password" name="password"><br><br>
    <span class="error hide"></span><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in">
  </form>



</body></html>